# Firebase auth email - prevent fake/invalid accounts

Tags: security, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase auth email accounts to sign up users to a site. 
What I have noticed lately is the below cases.

1. Users sign up using a valid email address and then never verify the
   email address
2. Users attempt to sign up using a fake email address

For the first case we can search all accounts that have not been verified within a time span and delete them.

```
admin.auth().getUser(uid).then(user => {
  const creationTime = user.metadata.creationTime
  const isVerified = user.emailVerified
  const lastSignInTime = user.lastSignInTime
  if(!isVerified){
    // Process and delete unverified accounts after x days
    ...
  }
})
```

How can we handle accounts where the email address is fake or misspelled? I am not seeing any property on the [firebase.User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User) object that indicates an invalid email address. We do however receive a mail delivery failure message for each user that has signed up using a invalid email address - this is not enough to automatically purge fake / invalid accounts.

What are best practices on preventing fake signups?

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop someone from using any string that looks like an email address, and the system doesn't have a way of telling you that the verification email was successfully sent.

The usual way to deal with this is to create some database record for each user account that tracks their validation status.  You can query the database to find out which users have not validated after some amount of time. Your app should be sending your backend ID tokens from the user that can be used to check if they are validated, and if so, update the database to show that it happened.

Comment: Thanks Doug for your prompt and helpful answer - as always! (^__^)/ Much appreciated! I already have db patterns in place and will make a scheduled function for purging old accounts that have not been verified. I will use the db record(s) representing unverfied users to fetch creation date data from firebase auth and compare that to a defined threshold. Many thanks! /K

Answer (score 1):

So this is the code I came up with to purge unverified accounts. 
May not be the most elegant solution, but works.

```
exports.scheduledUserCleanup = functions
.region('europe-west1')
.pubsub
.schedule('0 3 * * *')
.timeZone('Europe/Stockholm')
.onRun(async (event) => {
  const today = moment()
  const inactivityThresholdDays = 7 //Get purge threshold days

  let myPromises = [] //Collect all promises to carry out 

  //Search for users that have NOT validated email
  database.ref('user-signups').once('value', (usersSnapshots) => {
    usersSnapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
      const uid = snapshot.key

      // Get user from firebase auth
      admin.auth().getUser(uid)
      .then((firebaseAuthUser) => {
        const creationTimeStr = firebaseAuthUser.metadata.creationTime
        const isVerified = firebaseAuthUser.emailVerified
        const lastSignInTimeStr = firebaseAuthUser.metadata.lastSignInTime
        const neverSignedIn = (creationTimeStr === lastSignInTimeStr) ? true : false

        if(!isVerified && neverSignedIn){
          // Process and delete unverified accounts after 7 days
          const creationTime = moment(creationTimeStr)
          const daysSinceCreation = today.diff(creationTime, 'days')

          if(daysSinceCreation > inactivityThresholdDays){
            console.log('Remove user from db and Firebase auth', uid)
            myPromises.push( admin.auth().deleteUser(firebaseAuthUser.uid) )
            myPromises.push( database.ref(`user-signups/${uid}`).remove() )
          }else{
            console.log(`Keep for ${inactivityThresholdDays} days before deleting`, uid)
          }
        }
        return true
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Remove if not found in Firebase Auth
        const notFoundInFirebaseAuth = (error.code) ? error.code === 'auth/user-not-found' : false
        if(notFoundInFirebaseAuth){
          console.log('Remove user from db', uid)
          myPromises.push( database.ref(`user-signups/${uid}`).remove() )
        }
        return false
      })
    })
  })

  // Execute promises
  return Promise.all(myPromises)
  .then(() => Promise.resolve(true))
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error('Error', err)
    return Promise.reject(err)
  })
})
```